# Extract specific row - SelectCommand

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 5 rows of data coming into my database every 2 hours from a GSM modem and I require only the last (latest) row of data as thats the only relevant one but need all of the data for a chart...

Is there a way of using something to only recall one row after every fourth.

---

Example.

1pm 
23, 25, 20,99,21

3pm
34, 56, 55, 65, 30

only showing 21 and 30 in data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem... Does your data go into a DataTable? Can't you use dt.Rows[4] to fetch the correct row?

Comment: as such yes, but I dont want one row, i need many rows collecting 1 row from 5. So every 2 hours when 5 rows of data get inserted my chart, table only reads one). Does the dt.rows do this for me?

Comment: It could, you'll need a separate datatables, one for the chart and one (which is a subset) for the table. But we'll need to see more code for a better answer. Please add code to your question that shows us exactly how you insert data into the chart and into the table.

Comment: '<asp:SqlDataSource ID="chart" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ServerDBnew %>" 
                
        SelectCommand="SELECT TOP (420) Serial, DeviceLevel FROM TBLReadings ORDER BY DateReceived DESC">
                       
        </asp:SqlDataSource>' ----nothing special pal. and its not how i want it, so i didnt post it.

Comment: I added an answer that uses CTE to get every 5th row. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I am currently trying to use it pal - will let you know I get on. .net is my cryptonite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CTE:

```
WITH NumberedRows AS
(
    SELECT Serial, DeviceLevel, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateReceived DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM TBLReadings 
) 
SELECT *
FROM NumberedRows
WHERE RowNumber % 5 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following SQL statement to fetch the required data:

```
select top (1) from your table order by DateTimeField Desc
```

Comment: This only give me one row in total, I want many rows of data just called after every 4 so I get the 5th row. Such as 12345 23456 34567 45678 - calls 5,6,7,8.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so many information, need more for the exact solution.

But if the timestamp of the records differ and you already can select the 5 for 1pm and 3pm, then you can try something similar in the where clause:

```
timestamp = select max(timestamp) from (the_5_recs_for_the_given_intervall)
```

Hope you understand what I want to say!